# Bash script to create script with values embedded

Tags: bash, shell-script, freebsd, escape-characters

```
su "$uname" -c "cat > ~/scripts/syncdownloads.sh <<ENDMASTER
"#!/bin/bash"
login="$flogin"
pass="$fpass"
host="$fhost"
remote_dir="$fremote_dir"
local_dir="$flocal_dir" 

base_name="$(basename "$0")"
lock_file="/tmp/$base_name.lock"
trap "rm -f $lock_file exit 0" SIGINT SIGTERM
if [ -e "$lock_file" ]
then
    echo "$base_name is running already."
    exit
else
    touch "$lock_file"
    lftp -p 22 -u "$login","$pass" sftp://"$host" << EOF
    set sftp:auto-confirm yes
    set mirror:use-pget-n 5
    mirror -c -P5 "$remote_dir" "$local_dir"
    quit
EOF
    rm -f "$lock_file"
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM
exit
fi

ENDMASTER"
```

The above is my part of my code, basically I want a way to insert the values at the top of the file that the user has entered (from `login` to `local_dir`) but then leave the rest of the lines till the `ENDMASTER` statement exactly as they appear now.

I've tried commenting every line individually and together with single and double quotes but when I run the bash script it always completes the commands from `base_name` onwards regardless and when I open the file generated the rest is blank after `trap`.

I am new to bash so any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot find anything relevant on-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about turning parameter substitution in the here-document off? (See [Example 19-7 on www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html#EX71C) for more details.)

Maybe your script will look better like this (although it is still pretty dense):

```
su "$uname" -c "cat > ~/scripts/syncdownloads.sh << 'ENDMASTER'
###### Using `$()` to create a sub shell so that we don't have to escape 
###### special characters.
$(
###### The parameter substitution is on here
cat <<INNERMASTER
#!/bin/bash
login="$flogin"
pass="$fpass"
host="$fhost"
remote_dir="$fremote_dir"
local_dir="$flocal_dir"

INNERMASTER

###### No parameter substitution
cat <<'INNERMASTER'
base_name="$(basename "$0")"
lock_file="/tmp/$base_name.lock"
trap "rm -f $lock_file exit 0" SIGINT SIGTERM
if [ -e "$lock_file" ]
then
    echo "$base_name is running already."
    exit
else
    touch "$lock_file"
    lftp -p 22 -u "$login","$pass" sftp://"$host" << EOF
    set sftp:auto-confirm yes
    set mirror:use-pget-n 5
    mirror -c -P5 "$remote_dir" "$local_dir"
    quit
    EOF
    rm -f "$lock_file"
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM
    exit
fi

INNERMASTER
)
ENDMASTER"
```

This way you don't have to escape anything.

Answer (score 2):

Preceed the dollar signs with a backslash:

```
lock_file="/tmp/\$base_name.lock"
```

and so on.